# Teechart application crashing in iphone

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

when using steema Teechart, its working fine in simulator, but application crashing when using in iphone,

its shows following error

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.ApplyScroll () [0x00000] in :0
 at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.m__0 (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0
 at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIScrollView+_UIScrollViewDelegate.Scrolled (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView) [0x0000d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIScrollView.g.cs:991
 at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIScrollView.SetContentOffset (PointF contentOffset, Boolean animated) [0x00010] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIScrollView.g.cs:208
 at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.Draw (RectangleF rect) [0x00000] in :0
 at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
 at CropManageriPhone.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/vss1/VSS Projects/CP Live/CropManageriPhone04022013/CropManageriPhone/Main.cs:17

and We are using monotouch version 6.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution for this,

i set ZoomScrollStyle for the chart control,

_controller.chart.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyle=Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyles.Manual;